# Use of undeclared identifier 'cardNum'

Tags: c, cs50, undeclared-identifier

I'm using a function of the library CS50 on cs50's environment, and this is how you store a value on a variable gathering it with an input:

```
long i = get_long("Enter a long: ");
```

Here comes my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{

do
{
    long cardNum = get_long("Card number:\n");
}
while (0 <= cardNum <= 9999999999999999);


if (340000000000000 <= cardNum <= 379999999999999)
{
```

...and so on.

The issue WAS

> use of undeclared identifier 'cardNum'

I've added:

```
long cardNum;
```

BEFORE the do-while loop; PROBLEM SOLVED.

Comment: `long cardNum` should be declared before `do {`

Comment: Read about scopes and it will become clearer

Comment: Well you *shouldn't* use `long cardNum`, it should be `char cardNum[32]` and input a string. That lets you get directly to any digit, and does not lose leading zeros. You are going the wrong way.

Comment: Because if the user enters `001122334455` then `getlong()`  will return the `long` value `1122334455`. Now please tell me the first 2 digits of the card number, and whether *enough* digits were entered.

Comment: @mkrieger1 - it's a terrible idea to use integer types for account numbers like this: they look like numbers, but the only sane way to handle this is with strings.

Comment: Ditto with phone numbers.

Comment: @mkrieger1 various digits or sets of digits of the card number have particular meanings. In my example, what was the 2nd digit of the card number? You make life very difficult by entering a string, converting that to an integer, and reversing that back to individual digits with `/` and `%`, when you have that information to begin with.

Comment: Ditto with postal codes.

Comment: @WeatherVane While what you are saying is true for more advanced development, this is clearly a school task for beginners.

Comment: @klutt I suppose so, but packing an input string into an integer and then unwinding it is just hard work!

Comment: I got it right.

Comment: how do I flag the question as solved??

Comment: @SusannaDafna Take the [tour] and you'll see how things work here

Comment: bro, I'm taking a tour on C and Python and for real, nightmares. How do I post as solved?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `cardNum` in the do block. Declare it outside the block of do and your error will be gone.

Correct way -

```
long cardNum = 0;
do
{
    cardNum = get_long("Card number:\n");
}
while (0 <= cardNum && cardNum <= 9999999999999999);
```

In your case, you were getting error because `cardNum` is only scoped for do block and isn't visible inside the while because its scope ends as soon as it leaves the `do` block. This is why you are getting  `use of undeclared identifier 'cardNum'` as error. The compiler sees it as an undeclared variable inside the `while()` function.

**NOTE** : you are better off using `long long int` because maximum range of `long` is implementation based and might sometimes just be limited to `2,147,483,647` (most probably on 32 bit systems). You can also use `int cardNum[20]` or whatever your maximum limit is instead of `20`.

Comment: Well, `LONG_MAX` is `9223372036854775807`. So, I guess it can hold that. Corrected the second point

Comment: `LONG_MAX` is implementation-defined.

Comment: I have no idea what you are suggesting me now. Only Abhishek seems to be replying to the error I'm referring; No, I can't use a string as this variable, it's for the CS50's problem set 2, and it says it shall be a float. The input is a float, and I  should not use arrays.

Comment: Plus, I tried to declare the variable outside of the do while loop, it generated basically the same error, saying that the variable was already declared before the loop, (0 in the case), so...